# Understanding Event-Driven in NodeJS

Tags: javascript, node.js

Consider this simple example:

```
var BinaryServer = require('../../').BinaryServer;
var fs = require('fs');

// Start Binary.js server
var server = BinaryServer({port: 9000});
// Wait for new user connections
server.on('connection', function(client){
  // Stream a flower image!
  var file = fs.createReadStream(__dirname + '/flower.png');
  client.send(file); 
  sleep_routine(5);//in seconds
});
```

When a client connects to the server I block the event for about 5 seconds (imagine that time has some complex operations). What is expect to happen if another client connects (meanwhile)? One thing that I read about NodeJS is non-blocking I/O. But in this case the second client only receive the flower after the sleeping of the first, right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> One thing that I read about NodeJS is non-blocking I/O. But in this case the second client only receive the flower after the sleeping of the first, right?

That's correct, assuming that you are doing blocking synchronous operations for five seconds straight. If you do any file system IO, or any IO for that matter, or use a setTimeout, then the other client will get their opportunity to use the thread and get the flower image. So, if you're doing really heavy cpu intensive processing, you have a few choices:

1. Fire it off in a separate process that runs asynchronously, EG using the built-in child_process module
2. Keep track of how long you've been processing for and every 100ms or so give up the thread by saving your state, and then using setTimeout to continue processing where you left off
3. Have multiple node processes already running, so that if one is busy there is another that can serve the second user (EG. behind a load balancer, or using the cluster module)

I would recommend a combination of 1 and 3 if this is ever a problem; but so much of node can be made asynchronous that it rarely is. Even things like [computing password hashes can be done asynchronously](https://nodejs.org/api/crypto.html#crypto_crypto_pbkdf2_password_salt_iterations_keylen_digest_callback)

Comment: Something like this is not blocking synchronous operation. Right?
`function sleepFor( sleepDuration ){
    var now = new Date().getTime();
    while(new Date().getTime() < now + sleepDuration){ /* do nothing */ } 
}` But a C/C++ addon executing Image Processing could be, right? @Paulpro

Comment: @carduh Other way around. That loop is blocking, because there is no call to anything external from node and no setTimeout or anything. A call to an image processing tool would almost certainly be asynchronous since it will probably run in a separate process. A hint is, if a function accepts a callback or returns a Promise it is almost always asynchronous. Most likely an image processing call would accept a callback function for you to put the code you want to execute when it is finished. In the meantime the node.js thread is free to serve other requests.

Comment: @carduh The same thing is evident in the Javascript that runs in web browsers: http://jsfiddle.net/154n0bk1/ Using your blocking sleep, the 500ms timeout isn't able to be called until after the main thread finishes.

Comment: I used that function to test this situation in server.I changed the code to have 3000ms of sleeping in first client and 6000ms in second (then I connect the two clients at the about same time - refreshing the two tabs). And the image appears in the two tabs about 9000ms after the refresh and at exact same time. I dont know why... what I expect is 3000ms to load the image in first client and 6000ms to load in the second client. Thats not happening

Comment: @carduh `client.send( file )` is most likely reading from the stream asynchronously into a buffer and then doing a little bit of Javascript code to pass the buffer along to the client. If your two refreshes happen before that starts it will probably try to execute both sleeps before the little bit of Javascript to pass the buffer to the client gets to run. I think you'd see the behaviour you expect it you changed `sleepFor( 3 )`, to `setTimeout( sleepFor, 0, 3 );` which tells it to asynchronously call `sleepFor( 3 )` as soon as possible ( delay 0 ms ).

Comment: Thanks a lot @Paulpro

Answer (score 0):

No - the two requests will be handled independently. So if the first request had to wait 5 seconds, and for some reason the second request only took 2 seconds, the second would return before the first.

In practice you would have your server connection called a second time before the first one had finished. But since they have all different state you would normally be unaware of that.

Comment: This is wrong. Javascript is single-threaded and if the thread is busy for 5 seconds, no other client will be served (at least not from this process).

Comment: True - if "sleep_routine" is actually a busy wait where javascript is executing the whole time. In general, something like "sleep_routine" will actually be blocked waiting on files or some such, in which case node will be free to handle a second request. That is why it is such a good idea to use non-blocking I/O

Comment: I think the OP was specifically asking about blocking synchronous code running for 5 seconds straight. Regardless, I decided to remove my vote.